# rest api not found using springboot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

```
Not able to connect with rest-api using spring boot

this is my code->

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeManagementResource {


    @Autowired
    private Facade facade;

    @GetMapping(value="/employee",produces = "application/json")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        System.out.println("facade------------------------ " + facade);
        List<Employee> list = facade.getEmployeesFacade();
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

```
2019-07-31 12:52:17.412  INFO 11644 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-07-31 12:52:17.416  INFO 11644 --- [           main] c.n.e.EmployeemanagementApplication      : Started EmployeemanagementApplication in 5.838 seconds (JVM running for 6.197)
Hello World
2019-07-31 12:52:30.743  INFO 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-31 12:52:30.743  INFO 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-07-31 12:52:30.743 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2019-07-31 12:52:30.752 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2019-07-31 12:52:30.753  INFO 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2019-07-31 12:52:30.765 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/employeemanagement/api/employee", parameters={}
2019-07-31 12:52:30.773 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2019-07-31 12:52:30.774 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-07-31 12:52:30.778 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2019-07-31 12:52:30.779 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-07-31 12:52:30.779 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2019-07-31 12:52:30.785 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2019-07-31 12:52:30.786 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-07-31 12:52:30.787 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-07-31 12:52:30.817 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-07-31 12:52:30.818 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Wed Jul 31 12:52:30 IST 2019, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available,  (truncated)...]
2019-07-31 12:52:30.861 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2019-07-31 12:52:30.862 DEBUG 11644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a setup servlet context path.

> /employeemanagement/api/employee

is the url. 
Check you `application.properties` for `server.servlet.context-path`.

Comment: So do I have to add this path to my application.properties file using the ta you mentioned??

Comment: In your application.properties there's a server.servlet.context-path=/employeemanagement 
If you delete this, then your url will be /api/employee